# How to list some files with SQL select?

Tags: osquery

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running this `osqueryi` command:

```
osquery> SELECT * FROM file LIMIT 10;
```

returns no rows. Other tables like `users` are populated.

Do I need to "activate" something to populate the `file` table? Is there another table or some thing like the [ls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls) command?

Answer (score 1):

There are no need to "activate" something to populate the `file` table, test with

```
  SELECT * FROM file WHERE path = '/etc/group';
```

it is only an uggly way to send parameters to tables like `file`, `device_file`, `device_partitions`, etc.  that are flagged at [osquery.io/docs/tables](https://osquery.io/docs/tables/) with the  *"required in WHERE clause"* icon in some column.

They will fix the information problem with an error message, and perhaps better documentation, see [more details here at the issue discussion](https://github.com/facebook/osquery/issues/2216#issuecomment-230673550).